# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: RolePermission is not associated to Role

Tags: node.js

SequelizeEagerLoadingError: RolePermission is not associated to Role!

I am using Sequelize with MYSQL. I am getting SequelizeEagerLoadingError: RolePermission is not associated to Role! when trying to select data from related models using include.

I am having three models, Role, Permission and RolePermission. Here are my models:

//Role Model

```
 Role.associate = (models) => {
 

    Role.hasMany(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'role_id',
      as: 'users',
    });
  
    Role.belongsToMany(models.Permission, {
        through: models.RolePermission,
        as: 'permissions',
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
      });
    
  };
```

// Permission Model

```
Permission.associate = (models) => {
  
    Permission.belongsToMany(models.Role, {
      through: models.RolePermission,
      as: 'roles',
      foreignKey: 'perm_id',
    });
  };
```

//RolePermission

```
 RolePermission.associate = (models) => {
    
    RolePermission.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        foreignKey: 'role_id',
        as: 'role',
      });
      
      RolePermission.belongsTo(models.Permission, {
        foreignKey: 'perm_id',
        as: 'permission',
      });
  };
```

// trying to select data from related models

```
const data = await db.Role.findByPk(req.params.id, {
        include: [
          {
            model: db.RolePermission,
            as: 'permission',
             
          },
        ],
      });
```

What am I doing wrong.